# Задать таймер для итерации в foreach

Tags: php

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
  // выполнять через 5 секунд
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выполнять каждую итерацию через 5 секунд?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно просто ожидание

```
sleep(секунды);
```